# Fetch records matching exact values in list (array)

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables (report, tags, report_has_tags) and need to select record that only have mentioned tags.Below is the query I am using

```
SELECT r.*, rt.report_id, GROUP_CONCAT(rt.tag_id) as tag_ids, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name) as tag_names 
FROM report r 
LEFT JOIN report_has_tag rt ON r.id=rt.report_id 
LEFT JOIN tags t ON rt.tag_id=t.id 
WHERE r.id in (select report_id from report_has_tag where tag_id IN (1,2) group by report_id having count(1) >1 ) 
GROUP BY r.id  
LIMIT 990 OFFSET 0
```

this query returning all records that contains tags 1,2 as well as records containing tag 3,4. I just need records that have tag 1, 2 only not 3 or other tags.Please see attached image https://ibb.co/Gdr6TDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the report_ids that don't have the other tag_ids, you can achieve that with this query:

```
SELECT r.*, rt.report_id, GROUP_CONCAT(rt.tag_id) as tag_ids, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name) as tag_names 
FROM report r 
LEFT JOIN report_has_tag rt ON r.id=rt.report_id 
LEFT JOIN tags t ON rt.tag_id=t.id 
WHERE r.id in (
    select report_id from report_has_tag group by report_id having count(1) >1 and max( tag_id ) < 3
) 
GROUP BY r.id  
LIMIT 990 OFFSET;
```

You just need to set the max on the having to exclude the ones with a tag_id greater than 2.

Comment: Not working, same result , having count(1)= 2 was doing same thing  as max( tag_id ) < 3

Comment: @Irphan try it now, I forgot to get rid of the where.

Comment: Yeah, this is returning the correct result for now but I can see you removed `where tag_id IN (1,2)` and its an important part. If I change tags ids to (2,3,4), How would I get the result only for (2,3,4)  ? . Basically my search is working as per tags selection (dropdown multiselect). I need data as per tags selection.

Comment: Well that's a different question. Anyways that can be achieved by a min( tag_id ) > 1 and max( tag_id ) < 5; You can always use having group_concat( tag_id ) = '2,3,4';, if it's ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Then change

```
having count(1) >1
```

to

```
having count(1)=2 and not exists (select report_id from report_has_tag where tag_id not IN (1,2))
```

My version tests if there are exactly two tags associated with the given record and no other tag is associated with it.

Comment: using having count(1) = 2, returning 5 rows like in screenshot.It should return only one row .Please check screenshot